# react js setState очередь

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Компонент **А** получат с сервера сообщение и записывает его в **newMessage** . компонент **В** следит за **newMessage** и при обновлении вставляет его в массив и рендерит. Но если сообщения приходят быстро, то **newMessage** перезаписывается до того как обновится страница.

Пример:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {//предположим что это сервер присылает сообщения
     this.setState({
          newMessage:i
         });
}
```

Ожидаемый результат: 0 1 2 3 4.

На самом деле: 4.

Можно их как то поставить в очередь(средствами react)???

**UPDATE**

**COMPONENT A**

```
//msg {id:'...', content:'...', date:'...', ...}
    reciveMessage(msg){//<-- сюда сервер присылает сообщение.

       this.setState({
                  newMessage:msg
                 });
    }
```

**COMPONENT B**

```
//Компонент должен увидеть что **newMessage** изменилось и добавить его в  список. 
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let list = this.state.MyMessagesList.slice();
    list.push(nextProps.newMessage);

    this.setState({
           MyMessagesList:list
           });
    }
```

Comment: к сожалению для поставленной задачи невозможно использовать state или props. Пока кроме setInterval в голову ничего не приходит. Я возьму время подумать:)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по коду, вы каждый раз перезаписываете newMessage, чтобы получилась такая строка, нужно делать конкатенацию строк:

```
this.setState({ newMessage: this.state.newMessage + ' ' + i })
```

UPD: Извиняюсь, неверно написал, судя по документации:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Нельзя вызывать setState в цикле. Если они вызываются один за другим, то они группируются.

Comment: нет, это не строка. Это независимые сообщения(сложный объект присланный сервером). Я упростил для примера.

Comment: @user282446 у вас запросы как к серверу идут?

Comment: Нет, сервер присылает.

Comment: @user282446 на сервер запросы асинхронно идут?

Comment: Сервер присылает сообщение через signalR в метод в компоненте **А**. Когда и в каком количестве они приходят не известно. Цикл в примере я сделал просто что бы показать проблему (можно представить что это сервер который присылает сообщения, а все что внутри цикла - это метод который их принимает )

Comment: @user282446 смотрите, то что вы делаете, это перезаписываете каждый раз newMessage. Если сервер вам присылает объект, то можете воспользоваться Object.assign чтобы склеить объекты. Можете показать пример ответа от сервера?

Comment: Я знаю. В этом и вопрос. Есть ли в react  средства что бы поставить обновления свойства в очередь? Или что-то вроде этого. Собственно я уже почти написал свою очередь.

Comment: @user282446 если результаты запроса идут один за другим, то невозможно. Просто сейчас я вижу что у вас просто newMessage каждый раз перезаписывается, а не склеивается, поэтому сложно понять) можно от вас получить пример вашего цикла запросов?:)

Comment: обновил вопрос .....